# Queries in tuple relational calculus re employee department and minimum & maximum salary?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, relational-algebra, tuple-relational-calculus

I have to solve the queries using tuple relational calculus and I just want to know if I did them correctly. I'm using this database:

```
EMPLOYEE: fname , minit , lname, ssn , bdate , address , sex , salary , superssn , dno
DEPARTMENT: dname dnumber , mgrssn , mgrstartdate
DEPT_LOCATIONS: dnumber , dlocation
PROJECT: pname , pnumber , plocation , dnum
WORKS_ON: essn , pno , hours
DEPENDENT: essn , dependent_name , sex , bdate , relationship
```

Q1: Retrieve the names of employees who make at least $10,000 more than the employee who is paid the least in the Company.

```
{e.Lname, e.Fname | EMPLOYEE(e) AND (∃b) (EMPLOYEE (b) AND e.Salary >= 
10000 + b.Salary AND NOT (∃a) (EMPLOYEE(a) AND b.Salary > a.Salary))}
```

Q2: Retrieve the names of all employees who work in the department that has the employee with the highest salary among all employees.

```
{e.Lname, e.Fname | EMPLOYEE(e) AND (∃b) (EMPLOYEE (b) AND e.dno = 
b.dno AND NOT(∃a)(EMPLOYEE(a) AND a.Salary > b.Salary))}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

edit: Assume that only one employee can have the highest/lowest salary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing at the meaning of base relations, the natural language agrees with the calculus. Nb technically the answer can't be found if you don't give the meanings (*predicates*) for the base tables. As to whether you got those right answers via correct reasoning, you'd have to give yours. PS The *questions* are flawed if there can be multiple employees with highest or lowest salary.

Comment: Nb constraints don't need to be known in order to query, it's just that it's good to catch query specs that might be flawed.